# How do I get the current active locale in NextJS middleware?

Tags: next.js

The standard function to get the current locale in a NextJS application ( via the [router](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router) ) is problematic because the useRouter hook is not available to middleware. Is it possible to get the active locale from the middleware, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2):

The [NextRequest](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/server#nextrequest) object, which is available to NextJS middleware, provides locale data via the nextUrl function.